# Set iframe src from list of urls

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm having trouble setting iframe source dynamically. I have a page with n iframes and img elements and a list of urls. I'm trying to set each iframe's/ img's src attribute using a for loop.

My html is this:

```
<iframe id="iframe-1" width="400" height="300">iframe one</iframe>
<img width="400" height="300">image one</img>
<iframe id="iframe-2" width="400" height="300">iframe two</iframe>
<img width="400" height="300">image one</img>
<iframe id="iframe-3" width="400" height="300">iframe three</iframe>
```

Here is what I've tried. I've also tried :

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var sources =     ["www.google.com","www.yahoo.com","www.weather.com","www.bing.com","www.nytimes.com"];
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("iframe, src");

for (var i = o; i < elements.length; i++)
{
    elements[i].src = sources[i];
}
</script>
```

The source is not showing up in the iframes/ imgs. Is there a better DOM selector to use than querySelectorAll? or should I have elements query inside the loop? I've tried variations which have not worked.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0):

The urls you've specified can't be loaded in iframe for security reasons, these sites protect against clickjack attack. Clickjack attack can be protected through the X-Frame-Options response header, either "X-Frame-Options" value="DENY" or "X-Frame-Options" value="SAMEORIGIN". Through this header settings all standard websites protect against clickjack attack.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors in your code:

1) You are setting the variable `i` to character `o`. The line should read:

```
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)
```

2) Your iframes are missing `http`, so the correct way would be to add them to the array:

```
["http://www.google.com","http://www.yahoo.com","http://www.weather.com","http://www.bing.com","http://www.nytimes.com"]
```

After fixing these errors your script functionally works as intended.

You have to note that most popular sites use scripts or special HTTP header fields to prevent including them inside `iframe` elements. This is why these particular sites will not be possible to be displayed inside an iframe.

Answer (score 0):

### Objective?

I am a little bit confused with what you are trying to do. It appears you have a handful of iFrames on a page, and you have an array of URLs, and you want to update the iFrames on the page with those URLs.

### Obvious Issues

There are a few obvious issues that I observed with your initial post. First, the selector `"iframe, src"` makes no sense, because there is no `"src"` element. If you are attempting to select anything with a src attribute, you could use a selector like this: `"[src]"`.

Second, your for loop is incorrect. You are using the letter `o` instead of the number `0`. Your for loop should look like this:
`for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++)`

Finally, you should append the http:// to your URLs when adding them to the iFrame. You could also make it protocol agnostic by making your URLs in the following format: `//www.google.com`

### Suggestions

This approach in general is a bit odd, because you are going to have to add additional iframes to the page every time you want to add a new link to your array. Instead, why don't you simply insert a new iFrame for each URL?

### EDIT

As another user mentioned, many sites will block you from embedding them in iFrames. If you notice the `x-frame-options:SAMEORIGIN` header on Google.com for example, this is telling your browser that it should not display the website in a frame, unless that frame is being served up from the same domain.